# Alternative Eclipse Plugin Location

Tags: eclipse

I have Eclipse Mars installed in Windows 7 Professional and wish to install some Eclipse plugins from the Marketplace but my company's network will not let me past the firewall.  I have tried various settings such as;

```
Window >> Preferences >> General >> network Connection
```

But this doesn't work and I can't seem to get the company infrastructure to get me connected.  So what is the best alternative to obtaining plugins?  Is it best to use the Help >> Install new software or google the desired plugin and download and install it? I do not want to mess up my Eclipse install.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. get internet connection
2. download archive and use floppy disk or similar to get it into eclipse

Sadly getting the archives is sometimes not easy. Many distributors simply assume that everyone has internet connection.

In your company you might be behind a proxy that receives encrypted content, decrypts it and re-encrypts the content with its own certificate. If that is the case you have to provide those certificates at startup of eclipse to be able to use that proxy.

To do so export the certificates (for example in your usual browser) and add this to your `eclipse.ini`, after the `-vmargs` line:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=jks
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=C:\yourCompanyCertificate.jks
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=yourStorePassword
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\yourCompanyCertificate.jks
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=yourStorePassword
```

Comment: If you are having trouble accessing the repository so you can copy it somewhere else you can try [mirroring the repo](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_mirror.html?cp=2_0_20_3_0)

Comment: @slartidan Thanks for the response.  I apologise for the delay in responding.  I am getting nowhere with the internet connection.  So it looks like I need to go down the download and install option. Are there any guides for this available??

Comment: @JonahGraham Thanks for the response.  I apologise for the delay in responding.  I am getting nowhere with the internet connection.  So it looks like I need to go down the download and install option. Are there any guides for this available??

Comment: @AJF Only in the link provided in my comment above. If you ask a specific question on SO about how to install a specific plug-in offline I can help if it does not work.

Comment: @JonahGraham Thanks again Jonah.  I finally got round to looking at the link you provided.  My manager won't allow the downloading of a complete repository.  The two plugins I require at present are the Spring IDE and PHP.  I attempted using this URL https://marketplace.eclipse.org/ in the Help >> Install new software option and also the drag and drop of the plugin to the running Eclipse workspace but neither seem to work

Comment: OK, as I said, ask a question about that (not a comment here), i.e. include the exact error message you get for installing a specific plug-in and I can help. The comments don't allow for the richness of text/images to explain things properly.